# Can ioctl be used in OS X to set keyboard input?

Tags: macos, input, keyboard, ioctl

I would like to set the keyboard input on my Mac OS X to raw while my application is running. I found a [solution](http://www.gcat.org.uk/tech/?p=70) for this on Linux and was wondering if ioctl can be used in a similar way on OS X.

The manual page for ioctl tells me to look in sys/ioctl.h for macros and defines for specifying an ioctl request. Having visited sys/ioctl.h there is not much to see.